# Writing to a cell turns on ScreenUpdating in my VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I have a weird problem where Excel is behaving differently on my development machine and a testing machine.

In my add-in, I've turned off ScreenUpdating in several places for long running processes. On my machine this works fine. On the testing machine, Excel sets `ScreenUpdating = true` as soon as I write to a cell.

The following code demonstrates the issue for me.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

    MessageBox.Show(excel.ScreenUpdating.ToString());

    excel.ScreenUpdating = false;
    MessageBox.Show(excel.ScreenUpdating.ToString());

    Workbook workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    Worksheet w = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];
    ((Range)w.Cells[1, 1]).Value = "Test";
    MessageBox.Show(excel.ScreenUpdating.ToString());
}
```

On my machine, opening Excel gives three message boxes saying

"True", "False", "False".

On the test machine they say

"True", "False" and "True".

I've also stepped through with a remote debugger and watched the `ScreenUpdating` property change immediately after the cell value is set. Further, this isn't the only thing that resets `ScreenUpdating`. Adding or removing a Worksheet or Workbook will also do this.

The Excel version on each system is the same (14.0.6112.5000 (32-bit)).

What could be causing this? How can I fix it so that Excel respects my settings?

Comment: Does the test machine has got any other xla or addins in XLStart folder?

Comment: @Kiru Yes. There's a Bloomberg add-in that's installed. In fact, disabling it seems to fix the issue and re-enabling it brings it back. I guess I need to talk to Bloomberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other addins in Excel can interfere with that single global setting.

It is for that reason you are supposed to save the current ScreenUpdating state to a local variable before, and restore it after, each use.

Ignore the changing of that setting in the `ThisAddIn_Startup` event (as you would not normally do your work there anyway).

Comment: The ScreenUpdating variable is being reset *every time* I make a change. The code I posted was merely an example. In practice, regardless of where I set it, as soon as I write to a cell it gets set back to true.

Comment: Got you: In that case another add-in is catching the cell change event and resetting ScreenUpdating to true (which is a bug in the other add-in). Suggest you remove the other add-in or replace it if possible.

Comment: I think you are correct. I can't remove it because it's a business-critical add-in. But I can talk to the people who made and see if they know something of it.

Comment: It is a common result of other coders not following the above rule about restoring the previous state. They are likely setting to false, doing some processing, then setting to true without regard to the previous state. Amateurs! :) Good luck with getting a fix.

Answer (score 3):

I am experincing the same problem with ScreenUpdating (and other settings) being reset to true by the Bloomberg add-in with VSTO add-in. Their support are working on a solution but in the meanwhile the following solution works ok:

By hiding each sheet when interacting with its cells the screen won't update and you'll get the performance benefits. Make sure to not try to hide the last sheet as it will raise an error. Not sure if this is suitable for your project but it is a workable solution for mine.

Here is some example code in VB.NET to hide a sheet:

```
' Create a book with a single worksheet
Dim Book As Excel.Workbook
Book = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)


'% Create sheet variable
Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet
Sheet =  TryCast(Book.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

' Visible
Sheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible

' Hidden but user able to show
Sheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden

' Hidden for user as well
Sheet.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVeryHidden
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about this. Thanks. What's the code to hide a worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

If an add-in is interfering with your ScreenUpdating somehow, you can stop them form doing it by disabling events temporarily.  using `EnableEvents`.  It is possible that this will break the functionality of that addon, but it worked fine for my needs.